# Html editor asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, editor

Does anybody know of a good free html editor's that works well in most browsers? I'm using visual studio 2005, if that matters.

Thanks,
-Tesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx - The HtmlEditorExtender is an ASP.NET AJAX Control that enables you to extend the standard ASP.NET TextBox control with support for rich formatting.

or

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

or

http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 3):

CKEditor is a really nice one. It's not especially for ASP.NET but they have stuff for ASP.NET and even for SharePoint if needed!

http://ckeditor.com

From memory it used to work well with UpdatePanels too. And yes it does work well in different browsers.

Answer (score 3):

This one has been around forever and regularly updated. http://www.freetextbox.com/

Answer (score 2):

Check [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/10-best-wysiwyg-text-and-html-editors-for-your-next-project/). I've found jHtmlArea nice to work with.